# Laravel 4: Reusable Forms (Add / Edit page)

Tags: php, forms, laravel-4, laravel-blade

When we develop forms for CMS (for example an Add product page and a edit product page), we usually develop 2 pages. But this result in double work and harder in maintenance & amendment.

Is there any way that I can do a form to be reusable on both add / edit page with Laravel?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, provided that your add/edit form is identical. Here's a brief idea on how it can be done:

1. Load the form using **Form::model** binding (http://laravel.com/docs/html#form-model-binding) which will populate the HTML fields with current values (for editing) or empty (for new form)
2. Add a hidden field in your form, like the product_id which is either loaded or generated depending on whether it is an edit/new form
3. Upon submission to your controllers you can use something like this:

   ```
   //after form validation
   $new = Product::firstorCreate(array(
   'product_id' => Input::get('product_id')
   ));
   //assign the rest of the fields
   $new->save();
   ```

I hope that can give you an idea to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use more obvious approach:

1. [Former](http://anahkiasen.github.io/former/)  could be used both in views and controllers, so I use it in controller
2. I create simple private method that holds my form
3. Use it both in add and edit action